# What's wrong with this bib entry?

Tags: biblatex

```
@INCOLLECTION{Masson-Delmotte2021-ms,
  title     = "{IPCC} - Climate Change 2021: The Physical Science Basis.
                 Contribution of Working Group {I} to the Sixth Assessment
                 Report of the Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change",
  author    = "Masson-Delmotte, V. and Zhai, P. and Pirani, A. and Connors, S.L.
               and P{\'e}an, C. and Berger, S. and Caud, N. and Chen, Y. and
               Goldfarb, L and Gomis, M.I. and Huang, M. and Leitzell, K. and Lonnoy, E.
               and Matthews, J.B.R. and Maycok, T.K. and Waterfield, T. and Yelek{\c c}i,
               O. and Yu, R. and Zhou, B.",
  editor    = "{MassonDelmotte, V., P. Zhai, A. Pirani, S.L. Connors, C.
               P{\'e}an, S. Berger, N. Caud, Y. Chen, L. Goldfarb, M.I. Gomis,
               M. Huang, K. Leitzell, E. Lonnoy, J.B.R. Matthews, T.K. Maycock,
               T. Waterfield, O. Yelek{\c c}i, R. Yu, and B. Zhou (eds.)}",
  publisher = "Cambridge University Press. In Press",
  year      =  2021
}


@INCOLLECTION{Gulev2021-gi,
  title     = "Changing State of the Climate System -- Climate Change 2021: The Physical Science Basis. Contribution of
               Working Group {I} to the Sixth Assessment Report of the
               Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change",
  author    = "Gulev, S.K. and Thorne, P.W. and Ahn, J. and
               Dentener, F.J. and Domingues, C.M. and Gerland, S. and Gong,
               D. and Kaufman, D.S. and Nnamchi, H.C. and and Quaas,
               J. and Rivera, J.A. and Sathyendranath, S. and Smith, S.L. and Trewin,
               B. and Schumann, K. and Rose, R.S",
  editor    = "{MassonDelmotte, V., P. Zhai, A. Pirani, S.L. Connors, C.
               P{\'e}an, S. Berger, N. Caud, Y. Chen, L. Goldfarb, M.I. Gomis,
               M. Huang, K. Leitzell, E. Lonnoy, J.B.R. Matthews, T.K. Maycock,
               T. Waterfield, O. Yelek{\c c}i, R. Yu, and B. Zhou (eds.)}",
  publisher = "Cambridge University Press. In Press",
  year      =  2021
}
```

One of two bib entries work. Can you tell me what's wrong with the latter, please?

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrbook}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mini.bib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}


\begin{document}

\parencite{Masson-Delmotte2021-ms} %works
\parencite{Gulev2021-gi} %does not work - why?

\printbibliography \newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\bibliographystyle` in this place in the preamble should produce an error message. Never ignore error messages, you cannot expect proper output if there are errors in your document. If your editor hides error messages from you or makes them otherwise hard to find, you may want to seriously consider using a different editor.

Comment: The `editor` fields in the two entries, while not malformed as such, look wrong. The field should not contain "(eds.)" and it should list all names separated with `and` and without an outer pair of curly braces. It should be `editor = "MassonDelmotte, V. and P. Zhai and A. Pirani and S. L. Connors and C. P{\'e}an and S. Berger and N. Caud and Y. Chen and L. Goldfarb and M. I. Gomis and M. Huang and K. Leitzell and E. Lonnoy and J. B. R. Matthews and T. K. Maycock and T. Waterfield and O. Yelek{\c c}i and R. Yu and B. Zhou",`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` is a `BibTeX` command and does not work with `biblatex` (try [biblatex-apa](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa))
2. There are two consecutive `and` in the author field of `Gulev2021-gi`, removing one will solve the issue (there must have been a `biber`-warning).